# JTable coloring specific gridline in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer

I have this 8x8 table and and I want to color the grid of the first and the second cell at the very top of the table with red. My question is it possible to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Coloring a Table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004197/java-coloring-a-table-row) (the method is the same whether you are interested in colouring rows, columns, or individual cells)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jtable coloring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405206/jtable-coloring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT**: I deleted this because I thought this wasn't what OP wanted.  I'm undeleting it at OP's request.*

> I have this 8x8 table and and i want to color the grid of the first
>   and the second cell at the very top of the table with red. My question
>   is it possible to do this?

Yes of course.

One way to do it would be to extend an existing renderer and override the *getTableCellRendererComponent* method.

For example:

```
public class GridlineCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (
        JTable table,
        Object value,
        boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus,
        int row,
        int column
    ) {
        final Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if ( row == 0 && (column == 0 || column ==1 ) {
            cell.setBackground( Color.RED );
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

You then need to warn your JTable that you want to use this renderer for certain types of data.

For example if you want to use this for cells containing Integer, the following should work:

```
JTable myJTable = ...
myJTable.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new GridlineCellRenderer() );
```

Comment: Umm sorry I mean not coloring the background but coloring the gridline of those two cell?

Comment: Coz the command that i saw was just coloring the entire grid but not coloring the gridline of specific cells

Comment: @user1110191: it's not entirely clear what you want.  You insisted in your dupe that I undelete this, so here we go...  I still didn't understand if you want to draw a background color for a few cells (which my answer shows how to do) or if you want something else.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this it is really a great help ^^

Answer (score 3):

Because you want to affect only certain cells based on location rather than type, override [`prepareRenderer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) and return a component having a red `Border` for the desired cells. See also [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: +1 for the Border - that's the nearest one can come to coloring some gridlines (if that is the task), though it doesn't look nice: the real grid is shown as well, giving a double-gridline

Comment: @kleopatra: Good point; the grid and background colors are L&F dependent. Aqua defaults to white for both, while Metal uses slate-blue on white.